# php file showing blank page in browser

Tags: php

I am new to php, trying to get started with simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <?php
  echo "Hello";
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am working with vpn for school server, my files are visible visible via WinSCP. WHen I load the page, it is blank, the source code is alright, can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: When you view the source of the page in your browser, what specifically do you see?

Comment: I think you are not loading page via apache/nginx server ?

Comment: Does the file have the .php extension?

Comment: Thanks for reponses, @david I see exactly the same code as I posted in the ticket

Comment: @RonakDhoot school server i am using is an apache server

Comment: @MortimerCat I tried both .php and .html, in case of .php the file isnt even recognized